# Merge XML Section XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and I'm having some trouble convrting an xml file.

I need to know the XSLT code, I have a serialized xml (XML A) that I want to convert into XML B?

I'm un-sure how to merge the customer section into one section.

Thanks in advance

**XML A**

```
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <Policy>
      <diaPolicyId>8B71E21FEFF546A680DFE9DA40EC0711</diaPolicyId>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
    </Policy>
    <PolicyAddtional>
      <diaPolicyId>8B71E21FEFF546A680DFE9DA40EC0711</diaPolicyId>
    </PolicyAddtional>
    <Customer>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
      <Title>003</Title>
    </Customer>
    <CustomerAddtional>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
      <IsBirthday>false</IsBirthday>
    </CustomerAddtional>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Policy>
      <diaPolicyId>E835E227EA8F44F1BDCF346CE63541F3</diaPolicyId>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
    </Policy>
    <PolicyAddtional>
      <diaPolicyId>E835E227EA8F44F1BDCF346CE63541F3</diaPolicyId>
    </PolicyAddtional>
    <Customer>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
    </Customer>
    <CustomerAddtional>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
      <IsBirthday>false</IsBirthday>
    </CustomerAddtional>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

**XML B**

```
<Customers>
  <Customer>
      <diaPolicyId>8B71E21FEFF546A680DFE9DA40EC0711</diaPolicyId>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
      <diaPolicyId>8B71E21FEFF546A680DFE9DA40EC0711</diaPolicyId>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
      <Title>003</Title>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
      <IsBirthday>false</IsBirthday>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
      <diaPolicyId>E835E227EA8F44F1BDCF346CE63541F3</diaPolicyId>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
      <diaPolicyId>E835E227EA8F44F1BDCF346CE63541F3</diaPolicyId>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
      <diaCustomerId>STE/WIL/19650420</diaCustomerId>
      <IsBirthday>false</IsBirthday>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

UPDATED: Added XSLT Done So Far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="Customers">
    <combined>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@* | Customer/@*" />
    </combined>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please include the XSLT stylesheet you've come up with so far - even if it is not working. Then, identify the part that is problematic and that you need help with. If you're unsure about XSLT in general, delete this question and learn about the basics of XSLT instead.

Comment: sorry added the XSLT I have used done, I does'nt output anything at the moment.

Comment: "Then, identify the part that is problematic and that you need help with."

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way but I'm pretty new to this so some it would be great if you could point me in the right way

Answer (score 1):

You first need to learn about the [XSLT identity transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

On its own it copies all the elements as-is, which means you only need to write templates for the nodes you actually wish to change.

It looks you wish to remove the child elements of the **Customer** elements (although keep their children of such child elements). In which case, you just need to add this template to handle this

```
<xsl:template match="Customers/Customer/*">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

So "Customers/Customer/*" matches the elements you want to remove, (or rather, not copy to the output), and `<xsl:apply-templates />` will then carry on processing their children (which will be matched by the identity transform)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Customers/Customer/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the end I used dynamics in C sharp to merge my different classes together then serialize